# Text file comparison software

Tags: comparison, compare, notepad

Is there any software available to compare two text files for the differences between them. I have two CSS text files with me that i want to compare for the difference.

Comment: for windows you can download notepad++

Comment: This is useful for **Ubuntu** users: http://askubuntu.com/q/12473/62483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux or Mac OS, use diff on the command line:

```
man diff
```

On windows, try this:

http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp

Answer (score 1):

[araxis.](http://www.araxis.com/merge/)

Also check Visual Studio Extension [Code Compare](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b)

Answer (score 1):

WinMerge works well too for comparing text files and source code as well. And its free!